# RichTextBox in C# Word Wraps With Very Long Lines of Text and Word Wrapping Turned Off

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am trying to get a RichTextBox to stop wrapping long lines of text.  These long lines of text can be extremely long, sometimes millions of characters long.  These are embedded PDFs in HL7 that can sometimes be 100+ pages creating some extremely long lines.  I have word wrap turned off and I have tried adjusting the MaxLength and RightMargin properties to be set to 2147483647 along with trying to adjust it to be just the correct length of the text.  I believe the default on both those properties are already set to allow the maximum allowed but I tried adjusting them anyways just to see what results I would have.  I have even tried testing with some much shorter lines, <150,000 characters and it still wraps the text.  My last test was ~135,000 characters and I got 12 lines of wrapped code.  I think it wraps around 12,000 characters.  Below is the initialization of the component and then the second part of code includes a lot of the stuff I have tried but I have commented out at this point as the default settings seems to be the best out of everything I have tried.  I couldn't find anything in the documentation on RichTextBox that states there is a max characters per line or anything like that.  Is there a way to make extremely long lines of text to not wrap?

```
            this.richTxtHL7.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.richTxtHL7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 40);
        this.richTxtHL7.Name = "richTxtHL7";
        this.richTxtHL7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(995, 401);
        this.richTxtHL7.TabIndex = 0;
        this.richTxtHL7.Text = "";
        this.richTxtHL7.WordWrap = false;
        this.richTxtHL7.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.richTxtHL7_Click);
        this.richTxtHL7.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.richTxtHL7_TextChanged);
        this.richTxtHL7.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.richTxtHL7_CursorMoved);

            int maxCharacters = txtManip.getMaxLineCount(ref richTxtHL7);

        //MessageBox.Show(maxCharacters.ToString());
        richTxtHL7.SuspendLayout();
        //richTxtHL7.RightMargin = maxCharacters+2000;
        //richTxtHL7.RightMargin = int.MaxValue - 1000;
        //richTxtHL7.MaxLength = maxCharacters + 2000;
        //richTxtHL7.MaxLength = int.MaxValue - 1000;
        //richTxtHL7.RightMargin = 2147483647;
        //richTxtHL7.MaxLength = 2147483647;
        richTxtHL7.Text = richTxtHL7.Text;
        richTxtHL7.Text += "\n WordWrap=" + richTxtHL7.WordWrap.ToString()
                        + "\n RightMargin=" + richTxtHL7.RightMargin.ToString()
                        +"\n MaxLenght=" + richTxtHL7.MaxLength.ToString();
        richTxtHL7.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way.  No user wants to deal with millions of characters and an endless scroll.  Break down your data into edible chunks the user can process.

Comment: If you have ever seen HL7 with embedded PDFs you would know that isn't correct.  You will have maybe twenty to thirty lines of text you will want to look at, one of them is not the line with the embedded PDF.  All the other lines will be short pieces of text which you will be able to see and you don't want 100 lines of wrapped text from the embedded PDF.  You want it going off the screen just like I am asking for.  I don't want it in chunks.  I want one line with millions of characters.  This is similar to other HL7 editors.

Comment: No, I've worked with HL7.  No reason to display the encoded PDF data to the user.  Replace all that with just "<PDF FILE>" or something.

Comment: Lets try it this way, that isn't my requirement.  I want the data as I described but thanks for making a suggestion that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum line length I tested in C# or VB.Net is 14091. One character will wrap to second line if the line length is 14092.

In VB6, the line length can be as long as 32767. There are also several other functions/controls that work well in VB6 but not in VB.Net. This is why VB programmers are still not ready to move to either C# or VB.Net.

Answer (score 0):

If this is WinForms, I believe that the right margin of a RichTextBox is defined as an Int32 and if non-zero will actually impose a line length.

Try setting the right margin to 0.

Comment: That is actually what the default is set to.  Although it seems to give me the best results out of any change I have tried to make to it, the text still wraps around 12,000 characters or so it would seem.  It isn't even precise, one line may have several 100 more characters than another on the wrapping.  There isn't any breaks in the line of text either, it is basically one continuous stream of letters/numbers/characters without any spaces.

And yes, it is WinForms.

Comment: Could the text have a newline character within it?

Comment: Nope, there is no newline characters in it.  If I take the same text and plop it into something like Notepad++ or other HL7 editors it goes on forever without wrapping the text.  I am pulling these characters out of an actual HL7 message which have a very specific format in them due to them being sent in a TCP/IP stream and that includes beginning characters, carriage return/new line, and end of the sequence.  They never put those characters anywhere else in the stream as it would hose everything else up.

Comment: I don't really want to post the 150,000 characters of text I was using(or any of my bigger examples) as it will just eat up space on here.  You can google "base64 encode pdf" and the first site that comes up(not sure if I should mention the name on here) will allow you to feed it a pdf and it will output an example of an embedded PDF.  If I do it with a 3 page PDF I get ~124000 characters.

Comment: There's no need to post up the file, but RichTextBox will perform some formatting based on how in interprets the contents of your file. I was wondering whether you had looked at the actual contents (rather than the displayed) of the lines either side of the apparent wrap, just in case it has inserted or interpreted a newline/carriage return.

Comment: Yeah, I even tried going to the end of one of the lines and copying like 5 characters before and 5 characters after the wrap and pasting it back in and it doesn't wrap the text so I think it has to do with the size but for full disclosure I just noticed all the lines do wrap on either a plus sign or a number and the character before the wrap appears to either be a plus sign, number, or "/".